# Determining the principal value

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you determine the principal value of $(-1+i)^{3-i}$?

I am not sure if this is the correct method but I first did

$ln(-1+i)=log_{e} \lvert -1+i\rvert +iArg(-1+i)$

I am not sure if this correct but I got $\frac {-\pi}{4}i$ from the above equation.

Then I did $e^{(\frac {-\pi}{4}i)(3-i)}$

And got $e^{\frac{-\pi-3\pi i}{4} }$ for my principal value.

However, solutions say the principal value is $(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3\pi}{4}})^{3-i}$

Can someone explain to what I did wrong and how the correct principal value was determined?

Comment: Re: your first attempt, you what happened to $\log_e |-1+i| = \log_e \sqrt 2$?

Comment: I tried following an example online and their ln(-1+i) was just equal to the iArg value so I thought the loge doesn't matter so I left it out. Now thinking back on it seemed pretty dumb to assume that. But I am not sure how to solve it with the loge.